# computer software Operating System

Tags: scientific-linux

Is there any options to upgrade Scientific Linux from version 6.3 to 7.3? If so how can I do that? I've done google search, but there is only info about upgrading from version 6.3 to 6.6 or later 6x versions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

A simple google search came up with this documentation from Scientific Linux. There's even a suggest query "Scientific Linux Upgrade Path 6 to 7".

Source: http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/7.1/x86_64/os/sl-release-notes.html#_upgrading_from_sl_6

> **Caution**   There is no supported upgrade path from Scientific Linux 6 to
>   Scientific Linux 7.
>
> While it may be possible to move from SL 6 to SL7, Scientific Linux
>   does not recommend or support such action. We have deliberately not
>   provided any tools for such a migration. Warning  We believe any
>   attempt to upgrade SL 6 to SL 7 will leave your system in an unknown
>   and probably unsupportable state.
>
> **Tip**   Upstream provides an upgrade
>   toolkit for migrating their product from EL6 to EL7. Users who need
>   this functionality should consider deploying TUV’s supported product
>   line instead of Scientific Linux.

The correct way to do a major version upgrade, especially in this case where it is noted that version 7 is an entirely different version of Linux, is to:

- Backup your data
- Do a fresh install of the new version
- Restore your data

Comment: @VeeEhn In the case you think it solves your question,  can _accept_ the answer... :-)